# Register a runtime dependency in Castle Windsor

Tags: installation, castle-windsor, ioc-container

In a code I'm refactoring, I have the following situation:

```
void Plugin(IExternalService service)
{
    var facade = new Facade(
        new ExternalServiceWrapper(service),
        new Dependency1(),
        new Dependency2());
}
```

Where `Dependency1` and `Dependency2` are implementations of `IDependency1` and `IDependency2`.

How can I convert this to a registration within Windsor installer? I can't seem to figure our how to pass the instance of `IExternalService` to the container.

**EDIT** I'm not in control of the Plugin's creation. I'd like to use it as a composition root to wire all the dependencies.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want the container to invoke the Plugin method, or do you want to invoke the container from within the Plugin method?

Comment: I'm trying to have all the dependencies of the `Facade` (implements `IFacade` resolved with Windsor. Plugin's entry point must be my composition root, it happens sometime during runtime and I'm not in control of it.

Comment: So actually you'd not be invoking `new Facade` but rather `container.Resolve<IFacade>()`?

Comment: Yup! Unless there's another way, that's about right. I'm just not sure how to fluently make this registration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register an existing instance, you can use the Instance method:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IExternalService>().Instance(service));
```

Comment: In the end, this was all I needed. The container took care of itself. I just needed to specify it in the correct order in the installer.